# python response does not match with soapUI

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, pysimplesoap

When I access the web service using soapUI I get the correctly formatted text. 
But when I use the python code, I get a dictionary with all rows in a single allBusType key.

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
url = 'http://180.92.171.93:8080/UPSRTCServices/UPSRTCService?wsdl'
namespace = 'http://service.upsrtc.trimax.com/'
client = SoapClient(wsdl=url, namespace=namespace, trace=True)
print client.GetBusTypes()
```

The above code returns the following:

```
{'return': {'allBusType': [{'busName': u'AC SLEEPER'}, {'busType': u'ACS'}, {'ischildconcession': u'N'}, {'isseatlayout': u'N'}, {'isseatnumber': u'N'}, {'busName': u'AC-JANRATH'}, {'busType': u'JNR'}, {'ischildconcession': u'N'}, {'isseatlayout': u'Y'}, {'isseatnumber': u'Y'},....
```

As per the following screen, soapUI is returning all the bus stops as separate tag. (And not all stops in a single tag as above)

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:GetBusTypesResponse xmlns:ns2="com.trimax.upsrtc.xml.jaxb.model" xmlns:ns3="http://service.upsrtc.trimax.com/">
         <return>
            <allBusType>
               <busName>AC SLEEPER</busName>
               <busType>ACS</busType>
               <ischildconcession>N</ischildconcession>
               <isseatlayout>N</isseatlayout>
               <isseatnumber>N</isseatnumber>
            </allBusType>
            <allBusType>
               <busName>AC-JANRATH</busName>
               <busType>JNR</busType>
               <ischildconcession>N</ischildconcession>
               <isseatlayout>Y</isseatlayout>
               <isseatnumber>Y</isseatnumber>
            </allBusType>
```

I will like to know if this is python issue or the server issue.

For each entry there is opening and closing tag called "**allBusType**" in the soapUI response that is missing in python response.
Python output is returning a single row for all entries.

Comment: Which `pysimplesoap` version are you using and how have you installed it? Thanks.

Comment: # version 1.16 # !pip install  pysimplesoap

Comment: I do not insist on pysimplesoap. Any module/ script that returns the correct output (like soapUI response), is ok.

Answer (score 1):

[SoapClient](https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/wiki/SoapClient) returns a [`SimpleXmlElement`](https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/wiki/SimpleXmlElement) as stated in the first line of the SoapClient docs:

> A simple, minimal and functional HTTP SOAP webservice consumer, using httplib2 for the connection ad SimpleXmlElement for the XML request/response manipulation.

Therefore to view it as xml you need to call the `as_xml` method on the returned [`SimpleXmlElement`](https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/wiki/SimpleXmlElement):

> as_xml(pretty=False): Return the XML representation of the document

The following *should* work:

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
url = 'http://180.92.171.93:8080/UPSRTCServices/UPSRTCService?wsdl'
namespace = 'http://service.upsrtc.trimax.com/'
client = SoapClient(wsdl=url, namespace=namespace, trace=True)
results = client.GetBusTypes()
print results.as_xml()
```